# Why can't I save a new wallpaper to the System/Wallpaper folder?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, desktop-customization

When I try to save a new wallpaper to the `Windows/System/Wallpaper` folder in Windows 7 it says:

> You do not have permission to save in this location. Please contact an administrator.

Well, I'm the Administrator, so how can I save in this folder?

Comment: Why would you want to save it there?

Answer (score 4):

Without getting into where it *ought to be* saved, the work-around for this is to save to desktop and then move the file manually to the location, which will provide you with an admin confirmation prompt if you have priveledges.

This can happen in e.g. "Program files" folders as well.

Comment: This is a good/easy workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't suggest saving files to 'System'.  There is no reason to save files down to that location and its not a good place to play around.  My box is also Win7 and that directory doesn't exist.  The obvious choice here is to save to an alternate location..."My Documents" maybe

All that said if this must be done you likely just aren't logged in as administrator.  Administrator is a default account and has more privileges than a user that is designated as an Administrator.

Comment: Agree.  I usually save the files to a folder in My Pictures.  Wallpaper images can be anywhere on your system.